# Add Featured Image to Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I have a plugin that creates a custom post type, named *popup*. But it does not add the Featured Image Meta Box on the edit page. I can go in the plugin and add it like this.

```
'supports' => apply_filters( 'popmake_popup_supports', array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'author', 'thumbnail' ) ),
```

This works, until the plugin is updated. 
In My theme I have added this:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'popup'));
```

But that does not ad the Meta-Box to the Custom Post Type.

**Question:** Is it possible to add this feature outside of my plugin, maybe in my functions.php file, so I can update the plugin?

**EDIT:**
Ended up using the free plugin **Advanced Custom Fields**, which let med add more then one featured image. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: What happens if you just use `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')` without the `array()`? EDIT: This probably won't do anything, as the custom post type doesn't include support for thumbnails. Can you not add the custom post type manually? Do you have to use the plugin?

Comment: As you said, did not work, and did not change anything. The plugin does more then just create this. Right now I found a workaround with the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields".

Comment: Perfect would be if I could add ONLY this is my functions.php, and it would add this to the original.


$popup_args = array(
  'supports' => apply_filters( 'popmake_popup_supports', array( 'post-thumbnails' ) ),
 );

Answer (score 0):

Now you are using the right code in functions.php file.It will works. 
Please follow my instruction and use below line of code in functions.php file . 
Here is the code.

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'popup') );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
```

Now if still not works then please specify the priority of actions. 
See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

Like this :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup',2 );
```